# parsing date submitted by jQuery in Rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, datepicker

I use jquery_datepicker gem for selecting date in my form. However, datepicker passes param in the following format:

`{"appointment"=>{"starts_at"=>"04/07/2012"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"915"}`

However, Rails requires that the date params must be in the following form:

`"starts_at(1i)"=>"2012", "starts_at(2i)"=>"4", "starts_at(3i)"=>"7"`

How should I parse my starts_at and get it back in the latter format?

The reason I need to manually parse it, because for some reason, rails confused 04/07/2012 as Jul 04, instead of April 07 (as jQuery datepicker displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to form date picker string at client side:

```
$( "#starts_at" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        dateText = $.datepicker.formatDate(
            'mm.dd.yy',
            new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay)
        );

        inst.input.val(dateText);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Date.parse(str) method to get the correct value.

```
dt = Date.parse(params[: starts_at])

eg: >> Date.parse('04/07/2012')
=> Sat, 07 Apr 2012
```

Comment: This gives me `=> Wed, 04 Jul 2012`

Comment: @cbron You and Nilesh have different locales set up. That's the reason.